# How to set up the same Terraform formatting style in VSCode and Intellij

Tags: visual-studio-code, intellij-idea, terraform

I am setting up an environment to develop Terraform in VSCode.

I'm collaborating with another developer, who uses Intellij and I use VSCode.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NuIo7.png)

The red part on the left is the code written in Intellij, and the green part on the right is the code written in VSCode.

I want to set the ESLint to be the same for each other to set a consistent format. How can I do that?

And I already set up setting.json

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BgbD5.png)

Now i use extension

**HashiCorp Terraform** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=HashiCorp.terraform

**Terraform (forked)** https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=l2fprod.terraform-fork

Thanks a lot.

Comment: All Terraform integrations with Atom, VSCode, Intellij, and Sublime  have auto-formatting capabilities with `terraform fmt` for canonical formatting. Based on your images, it appears to have been enabled by the user in VSCode but not yet in Intellij. The person using Intellij would need to also enable it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `terraform fmt` command is used to rewrite Terraform configuration files to a canonical format and style. This command applies a subset of the Terraform language style conventions, along with other minor adjustments for readability.

https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/fmt

Rather than changing the formatting in your IDE's you should run the `terraform fmt` command which will format your code to correct formatting.

Comment: Thanks! but i just want to know same auto-formatting in VSCode and Intellij. Could you give me advise about that?

Comment: The IntelliJ Terraform plugin uses the `terraform fmt` command to format Terraform files.

Answer (score 5):

You can use IntelliJ `file watcher` feature to automatically run this on every file change (**very useful**).

Go to `Preferences -> Tools -> File Watchers` and config it just like the picture below.

[image]

Comment: If you don't find it (like I did), the plugin https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7177-file-watchers/versions#tabs is required

Comment: Once I installed the IntelliJ Terraform plugin, the above config was automatically selectable form a pre-filled "terraform" file watcher template